# How to replace multiple same word in string with different words

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace multiple same word in string with different words.

For example,

```
"What is your %s name and %s name"
```

I want to replace first `'%s'` with `'first'` and second `'%s'` with `'last'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be cleaner:

```
['first', 'last'].forEach(function(tag) { x = x.replace('%s', tag); })
```

where x is the string you want to substitute into.

Comment: For a beginner like the OP I respectfully disagree.

Comment: Was the OP looking for an answer or an education?

Comment: how could this be simpler?

Comment: Well `['first','last'].forEach( tag => x = x.replace('%s', tag) );` would be "simpler", but one must walk before they run...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a string as the first arg to replace it only does 1 replace.

```
var s = "What is ... ";
var r = s.replace("%s", "first")
         .replace("%s", "last");
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) as callback for replacing `%s`.

This solution uses `shift`, because it serves a value from the array for each call, if an item for replacement is found. Usually a string or a function is needed as second parameter for `replace`. This proposal uses `shift` with a binded array for replacement.

[`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a function with the binded object.

> The **`bind()`** method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
var s = "What is your %s name and %s name?",
    t = s.replace(/%s/g, [].shift.bind(['first', 'last']));

console.log(t);
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but your answer could use some explanation of HOW this works.  For starters how `func.bind()` works... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @JohnHascall, maybe this is now better explained.

Comment: Better.  Might also mention that `[].shift()` is really `Array.prototype.shift()` because `[]` is an Array literal.

Comment: i wrote it in the first line, with a link.

Comment: BTW, there is a similar 'fat arrow' approach: `t = s.replace(/%s/g, () => ['first', 'last'].shift() );`